# sequence is bounded below

Tags: analysis

I have to show that the sequence $$c_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}-\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx$$
is bounded below.

I have thought the following:

$$c_n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+ \cdots +\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}-\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx \geq \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n} \cdots \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n}-\int_1^n \frac{1}{x^2}dx=n \cdot \frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{x}|_1^n=1+\frac{1}{n}-1=\frac{1}{n}>0, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

Therefore,$f$ is bounded below by $0$.Could you tell me if it is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $x \ge 1$, $1 \ge \frac 1x$, hence $\frac 1x \ge \frac 1{x^2}$, which means 
$$
- \int_1^n \frac 1{x^2} \ge - \int_1^n \frac 1x,
$$
so you got this term the wrong way around.

If you want a hint, say so ; I will gladly help.

Hint : 
$$
\int_1^n \frac 1x \, dx = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_i^{i+1} \frac 1x \, dx, \quad \frac 1i = \int_i^{i+1} \frac 1i \, dx.
$$
What happens with your sequence on each subinterval $[i,i+1]$?

Hope that helps,

Comment: Yes,any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: @evinda : I edited my answer.

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!! $\checkmark$

Answer (score 1):

Your inequality isn't valid since

$$\int_1^n\frac{dx}{x}\ge \int_1^n\frac{dx}{x^2}$$

To prove the result we have

$$c_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x}=\frac1n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\underbrace{\frac1k-\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{x}}_{\ge0}\right)\ge0$$

Answer (score 1):

You could think in terms of Riemann sums. Since $f(x) = 1 /x$ is a decreasing function if you use left endpoints $x_i = i$ with length of subintervals $\Delta x = 1$, you will get:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Delta xf(x_i) \geq \int_1^n \frac{1}{x}\; dx \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} \geq \int_{1}^n \frac{1}{x}\; dx
$$

Comment: Great,thanks!!!